# Merge two different rows in a table if most of the columns hold the same data except two which are alternatingly null

Tags: sql, select

I have the following table:

```
Id      Included    Excluded
13235   null        B,D
13235   E           null    
13236   null        D
13237   null        B,D
```

The included and excluded columns will be filled only alternately. 
In the result, I would like to see the Included and Excluded columns to be merged into one row for the Id 13235. My result should look like the following:

```
Id      Included    Excluded
13235   E           B,D 
13236   null        D
13237   null        B,D
```

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `MAX`

```
SELECT  ID, 
        MAX(Included) Included,
        MAX(Excluded) Excluded
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3d972/1)